# How to display new input data after submittion using Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Please help me out of this!.
After i submit the new input variable doesn`t display in the div.

Here is my Script:

```
    $('#addVariable').validate({
        rules: { variable: {required:true}} ,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
                var id = $('input[name="compid"]').val();
                var name = $('input[name="variable"]').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://localhost/scorecard/wp-
    content/themes/twentyseventeen/ajax/submit.php?function=addVariable",
                    type:"post",
                    data:{ company_id:id , variable_name:name},
                        success: function(data){
                            if(name === " "){
                                alert(data);
                            }
                            else{
                            alert('success');
                            $('input[name="variable"]').val(' ')
                            }
                        }
                });
        }   
     });
```

Here is my form code:

```
    <form id="addVariable">
                    <input type="hidden" id="hidId" name="compid">
                    <input type="text" class="variable" name="variable" 
    value="">
                    <input type="submit" class="btnVar" value="" onclick="">

                    <!--<input type="button" class="remove" value="-">-->
                  </form>
```

Comment: are you getting response ?

Comment: i actually use response earlier but still no luck.

Comment: you ajax call is not working form submited. please check

Comment: It is working..

Comment: can you tell me what is the error or what are you getting in alert

Comment: please read the title

Comment: $('input[name="variable"]').val(' test'); try it without condition is it working ?

Comment: yes it is working..

Comment: All i wanted is how to display the new variable name into my div without refreshing the whole content

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is the following part

```
variable_name:name},
success: function(data){
if(name === " "){
alert(data);
}
```

If I am correct the closure called here does not have access to the name variable, as it is in a different scope.

If you want to use the name variable, either send it as a parameter or bind it to the fuction. Try:

```
success: function(data){
    if(name === " "){
        alert(data);
    }
    else{
        alert('success');
        $('input[name="variable"]').val(' ')
    }
}.bind(name) // bind name to the function
```

Answer (score 1):

1. According to your code, you want to change the value of the input `<input type="text" class="variable" name="variable" value="">` to empty string, after the successful response from ajax. Is it correct?
2. Anyway, you can debug it from the console, to see if you actually get a successful response.

   ```
   success: function(data){
      if(name === " "){
         //alert(data);
         console.log('data ', data); 
      }
      else{
        //alert('success');
        console.log('success'); 
        $('input[name="variable"]').val(' ')  
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: or use debugger to check the variables in the script

Comment: i dont have a problem about the input into empty.
My problem is after i submit the variable it will appear in my div.

Comment: i dont have problem with my code, what i wanted is after i submit it will display in my DIv tag the new variable i was inputed

Comment: sorry, where is your `<div>` tag, is it outside the `<form>`? , how about try to use the id of the element?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
if(name){
$('input[name="variable"]').val(name)
}
else{
alert('name is not available');
}
```